# Mapping out sculpted details from a high-poly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, uv, sculpting

**I need to bake a map in order to separate different colors and materials on the low poly model.** [image]

The padding part is easy because it is a separate object. But the scratches are sculpted and I don't know of anyway to create a uv map of those details(alone from the rest of the object). Is there a way for me to do this without painstakingly painting every small detail manually?

**EDIT FOR CLARITY**

I need to generate a map from sculpted detail (from the Highpoly) in order to have different material proprieties on the same object (the lowpoly).
[image]

Comment: I think what you want to do is bake a normal map, then apply it to a low-poly model.  Decimate modifier may help with that step.  Look up "Blender bake normals" on YouTube, and you should find what you need.

Comment: No, I need a grey-scale map to differentiate the scratches and scrapes from the rest of the surface of the same object.

Comment: "Normal maps can be referred to as a newer, better type of bump map."  https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/film-games/bump-normal-and-displacement-maps

Comment: I don't need a normal map. I don't know how else I can explain this.

Comment: Bake a normal map.  Open it in Gimp, discard the red and green channels.  Convert the blue channel to greyscale, because that's the channel that contains the Z-axis.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping

Comment: The blue channel has little or zero of the detail in question. And I've already tried fiddling with colors/thresholds/levels on a normal map.

Comment: For something like this you generate a curvature map. but I haven't found a solution for this in Blender. Normally I bake curavture maps with substance designer[$] or with XNormal[Windows]. or maybe render a ambient occlusion map. But in my opinion it is not possible to change settings of the ambient occlusion rendering. But somebody, enlighten me !

Answer (score -1):

I dare to post this answer, because the following tool is free and in my opinion everyone should know this great piece of software. Please forgive me! :-)

After some testing the best working solution I found so far can be archived by creating a heightmap in XNormals. Therefore I hope that you are on a windows system, because XNormals is a pure windows tool.

1. Export your highpoly and your lowpoly  and a cage as seperate Fbx scenes.

[image: Sources]

2. Import them to XNormal (just drag the highpoly and the lowpoly into the list).

[image: Highpoly and Lowpoly]

for the cage, a checkbox in the lowpoly object has to be enabled and you have to select it by clicking with RMB in the sceen and select "Browse external cage file"

[image: cage file]

3. In the baking option select your texture size you want to export, your export location, and check heightmap as renderer.

[image: Baking options]

4. To render, press the Generate Maps button and after some calculating something like this should appear:

[image: Heightmap]

After adjusting your heightmap, close the window  and it will export it to your predefined export location.

Comment: This is the type of thing I've been looking for. However, in my bake, the topology is clearly visible and it's drowning out the detail. In blender I could just set the shading to smooth but I'm not sure how to fix this with xNormals. https://i.imgur.com/tEvf5UN.png

Comment: Hm that’s bad. Maybe you can try to give your lowpoly only for the baking process a subdivision surface modifier.